Unable to view the image which are uploaded from node js
After uploading the images to the S3 bucket, I am able to upload them successfully. However, when I try to view the image using the S3 URL, something else appears instead of the image.

i want to upload images from node js using presigned url.
import { GetObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { s3 } from "../awsConfig";
import { generateAlphanumericOTP } from "./otpHandler";

export const getObjectURL = async (key: string) => {
 try {
   const command = new GetObjectCommand({
     Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
     Key: key,
  });
 const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command);
 return url;
  } catch (error) {
 console.error("Error getting object URL:", error);
 throw error;

}
};
const uploadReviewImage = async (filename: string, contentType: string) => {
try {
const command = new PutObjectCommand({
  Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
  Key: `reviewImage/${filename}`,
  ContentType: contentType,
});
 const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command);
 return url;
} catch (error) {
 console.error("Error uploading review image:", error);
 throw error;

}
};
export const initUpload = async () => {
  try {
   const url = await 
   uploadReviewImage(`Image-${generateAlphanumericOTP(4)}.jpg`, 
  'image/jpg');
   return url;
 } catch (error) {
 console.error("Error in initUpload:", error);
   throw error;
 }
};


That "error" is your form content, with the multipart boundary and the image data.
